# How can you see all the contents of a variable in a coldfusion template?

Tags: coldfusion, cfdump

In PHP for example you can do:

```
<?= var_dump($myVariable); ?>
```

And see a dump of the entire variable with all it's available properties. How can you do this in a coldfusion template with a `.cfm` extension (in other words in the view layer not controller)?

Comment: <cfdump var=#variable#> something like this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`<cfdump var="#myVariable#">`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdump.html). If you use the script-syntax (cfscript), it's `writeDump(myVariable);`.

Note that dumping within a function or component might not display anything due to how the output buffer works in CF. In this case, use the `abort="true"` attribute of `cfdump` or abort manually after the dump by placing `<cfabort>` (cftag) or `abort;` (cfscript).